# How to use plock(HPUX) on Linux

Tags: c, linux, porting, hp-ux, memory-locking

I am porting a HP-UX program to Linux. There IS

```
plock(PROCLOCK);
```

Should I use `mlock()` to instead of it?

Also the original code did not call `plock(UNLOCK)`, not sure why, but I should add `munlock()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SunOS 5.10 man page for [`plock(3C)`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?plock%203) says:

> **USAGE**
>
> The [`mlock(3C)`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?mlock%203) and [`mlockall(3C)`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?mlockall%203) functions are  the  preferred interfaces for process locking.

Considering `plock` is not available in Linux, yes `mlock` is the correct alternative.

The Linux man page for [`mlock()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) says:

> Memory locking has two main applications: real-time algorithms and high-security data processing.

If your application falls under one of those two categories, then I would say yes, it makes sense to call `mlock()`. I can't think of any reason you would call `munlock`, but your specific program requirements may be different.

The man page has further guidance on how exactly you should call it to attain the desired results. Without knowing what your program does, or why the original author decided to call `plock`, that's the best advice I can give.